# How to make public directory of my framework the default one in Vagrant?

Tags: frameworks, virtualization, virtual-machine, virtualbox, vagrant

I am using **[Vagrant](http://vagrantup.com/)** to set up my local development environment. I managed to do port forwarding from port 80 on my Virtual Machine (lucid64) to my host port 8080. If I put an index.html file in my project folder and type 'localhost:8080' in my browser, I see the html page displayed. So far so good.

The thing is I work on a framework which has this directory structure:

```
app
**public**
vendor
tmp
```

where the public folder should be the 'root' folder.

So I edited the project.conf file located at /etc/apache2/sites-available in my Virtual Machine to:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /vagrant/public
</VirtualHost>
```

(I simply added the '/public' part).

Now when I go to localhost:8080 in my browser, **it downloads the index.php file in the public folder instead of displaying it. How can I fix that please?**

Answer (score 1):

Is PHP properly installed and enabled in you apache configuration? I don't think this is connected to vagrant.

Comment: Hi I restarted from scratch and installed apache2, mysql and php5 on my VM and made sure they were all up and running. I pointed to the public folder as before. Now I get a HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error) when I type localhost:8080 in my browser. I thought that must had something to do with the .htaccess, but it works in my host machine on MAMP and the module mod_rewrite is already enabled in my VM. I have no clue what's going on.